# What is the idea behind the derivation of $z$-score formula?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I can't fully wrap my head around the reasoning behind the $z$-score formula.
$z = (x - \mu)/\sigma.$ Can someone explain how this formula was derived or how it works?

Edit: I understand why and how the formula and concept is used. I just don't get how that exact formula is able to create a mean of 0 and standard deviation of one. I don't see much tutorials or sites explain this thoroughly. It's only that, they just give the formula and say that it produces a mean of zero and standard deviation of one.

Yes, I see explanations seeing that you subtract the random variable X by the mean to make the mean zero. Also, you divide that entire quantity by the standard deviation to make it one. But can someone explain why it works? I don't get why it works.

Comment: There is a ton of information online about the standard score. You may want to consider making your question much more concrete; otherwise, you will just get at most a duplicate of what you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score).

Comment: It is a way of normalizing the distribution to mean 0 and std. dev. 1 for table lookup.

Comment: Yes I understand the purpose. But what I do not get is how the formula for the z-score was actually derived. Can someone explain why that exact formula is used and how do I conceptually come up with it on my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This boils down to two facts for (real-valued) random variables: first, linearity of expectation:
$$ E[aX+b] = aE[X]+b $$
and this property of variance:
$$ \text{Var}[aX+b] = a^2\text{Var}[X] $$
Applying these formulas, if $X$ is a normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and $Z=(X-\mu)/\sigma$ then
$$E[Z]=E\left[\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right]=\frac{E[X]-\mu}{\sigma}=\frac{\mu-\mu}{\sigma}=0$$
and
$$\text{Var}[Z]=\text{Var}\left[\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right]=\frac{\text{Var}[X]}{\sigma^2}=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2}=1$$
Therefore $Z$ has mean $0$ and variance $1$. Also, we know that linear transform of a normal random variable is still normal, therefore $Z$ is the standard normal distribution.

Comment: This is a really wonderful explanation. It makes me more interested in studying properties of expectation and variance. Thanks.